# Forward emails with PowerShell and EWS Managed API

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a PowerShell Script that uses EWS Managed API to fetch and processes specific emails from an inbox. If an email doesn't meet a condition its then forwarded to another inbox. the script works fine, but if it finds emails with attachments (that don't meet condition), it gets stuck to Draft folder and doesn't get sent. Any ideas?

The part of the code that forwards the emails.

```
    Else {
      $mail = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage($service)
        $OriginalEmail = $findResults.Items[0]
        $psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::IdOnly) 
        $psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::MimeContent)
        $psPropset.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject)
        $OriginalEmail.Load($psPropset)
        
        # Delete Received email after gathering the data
        $findResults.delete([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::MoveToDeletedItems,$True)

        $AtColtype = ("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AttachmentCollection") -as "Type"
        $Emailtype = ("Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage") -as "Type"
        $methodInf = $AtColtype.GetMethod("AddItemAttachment");
        $AddItmAttachMethod = $methodInf.MakeGenericMethod($Emailtype);
        $EmailAttachment = $AddItmAttachMethod.Invoke($mail.Attachments,$null);
        $EmailAttachment.Item.MimeContent = $OriginalEmail.MimeContent
        $PR_Flags = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer);
        $EmailAttachment.Item.SetExtendedProperty($PR_Flags,"1");
        $EmailAttachment.Name = $OriginalEmail.Subject;
        $mail.Subject = "$Subject";
        $mail.ToRecipients.Add($ForwardToEmail);
        $mail.SendAndSaveCopy();
        $mail.Close()
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the draft messages have the attachment attached and the subject/address set correctly? If you run the commands manually, does an error message get generated?

Comment: There are simpler methods for forwarding emails too, like `emailMessage.Forward(messageBodyPrefix, addresses)` or `$responseMessage=$emailMessage.CreateForward();<#add details#>;$responseMessage.SendAndSaveCopy()`. What version of exchange/ews are you using?

Comment: Thanks guys, as We have System Center Orchestrator, I decided to use Forward Email feature (wasn't working before) to achieve this. I am now using PS + EWS Managed API to get Id of the emails that don't meet a condition and Orchestrator uses their Id to target and forward them.